# Problem when changing your nickname Discord.py

Tags: python, discord.py

I want to make a command that changes the nickname of a particular user, I wrote this code:

```
async def chnick(ctx, member: discord.Member, nick):
    await member.edit(nick="test")
    await ctx.send(f'Nickname was changed for {member.mention} ')
```

python throws this error:

```
Ignoring exception in command chnick:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\bot.py", line 903, in invoke
    await ctx.command.invoke(ctx)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 847, in invoke
    await self.prepare(ctx)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 784, in prepare
    await self._parse_arguments(ctx)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 690, in _parse_arguments
    transformed = await self.transform(ctx, param)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 535, in transform
    raise MissingRequiredArgument(param)
discord.ext.commands.errors.MissingRequiredArgument: member is a required argument that is missing.
```

please, help me!

Answer (score 0):

You did not specify a member to edit. Also you should pass your `nick` parameter to `member.edit()`. Your command should look like this: `!chnick @member john`

```
@client.command()
async def chnick(ctx, member: discord.Member, *, nick):
    await member.edit(nick=nick)
    await ctx.send(f'Nickname was changed for {member.mention} ')
```